# How do I add a listener to multiple markers which call the same function to display directions on click in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-directions-api

```
var x1 = 0;
var startPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
var endPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
var marker;
var latlngs = new Array();
var infowindow;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var locations = [
   {
       "name": "Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too",
       "address": "939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA",
       "lat": 37.386339,
       "lng": -122.085823
}, {
       "name": "Amici's East Coast Pizzeria",
       "address": "790 Castro St, Mountain View, CA",
       "lat": 37.38714,
       "lng": -122.083235
}, {
       "name": "Kapp's Pizza Bar & Grill",
       "address": "191 Castro St, Mountain View, CA",
       "lat": 37.393885,
       "lng": -122.078916
}, {
       "name": "Round Table Pizza: Mountain View",
       "address": "570 N Shoreline Blvd, Mountain View, CA",
       "lat": 37.402653,
       "lng": -122.079354
}];
```

Edit: these are the global variables just to clarify ^

I want create a "click on markers to get directions" functionality. So far I have created a list in JSON that creates all the markers from the "lat" and "long" in the list without a problem:

```
for (var k in locations) {
       latlngs[k] = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[k].lat, locations[k].lng);
       marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latlngs[k],
           animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
           title: locations[k].name,
           map: map
       });
   };
```

The JSON list ( locations[k] ) is 132 locations in total. I want to be able to click on a marker, save it as a start point for directions then wait for the secnond marker to be clicked on, which will be saved as an end point. Clicking the second marker will calculate and show directions as Iv'e tried below:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
       if (x1 === 0) {
           startPoint = this.marker.position;
           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
               content: "Start",
               position: startPoint
           });
           infowindow.open(map, this.marker);
           directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
           directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));
           x1++;
       } else {
           endPoint = this.marker.position;
           x1 = 0;
           calculateDirections(startPoint, endPoint);
       }
   });
```

At this point no infowindow gets displayed and I get the error saying "cannot read 'position' of undefined". I can get the directions to show when I hardcode the start and end points.

The following threads touches on the same idea but don't answer the listener for all markers problem, which I think is the main issue.

[Google Maps API V3 - add event listener to all markers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611634/google-maps-api-v3-add-event-listener-to-all-markers)

and

[how do I add same event listener to many markers and then differentiate between the markers in the listeners in google maps api v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705175/how-do-i-add-same-event-listener-to-many-markers-and-then-differentiate-between#)

Comment: Do you want to get the position of marker by Click on map?

Comment: I want to use the listener on multiple markers, clicking the first, get the position of it, then clicking the second, save it individually as start/end point, then calculate the directions after the end point is clicked

Answer (score 0):

If you get the LatLang on click then saving it wont be a big deal. I have tried to achieve this on click and get the latlang. I am not sure how much this will solve your problem but definitely will give you some idea to move ahead.

Here is the working example, and I hope this will help you.

```js
      var map;
      var geocoder;
      var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
                zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

      function initialize() {
var myOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
                zoom: 10,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                placeMarker(event.latLng);
            });

            var marker;
            function placeMarker(location) {
                if(marker){ //on vérifie si le marqueur existe
                    marker.setPosition(location); //on change sa position
                }else{
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({ //on créé le marqueur
                        position: location, 
                        map: map
                    });
                }
                document.getElementById('lat').value=location.lat();
                document.getElementById('lng').value=location.lng();
                getAddress(location);
            }

      function getAddress(latLng) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
          function(results, status) {
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
              if(results[0]) {
                document.getElementById("address").value = results[0].formatted_address;
              }
              else {
                document.getElementById("address").value = "No results";
              }
            }
            else {
              document.getElementById("address").value = status;
            }
          });
        }
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script><input type="text" id="address" size="30"><br><input type="text" id="lat" size="10"><input type="text" id="lng" size="10">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
```